# Prove $BO(n) = G_n(\mathbb R^\infty)$

Tags: algebraic-topology

For each $n$ the space $BO(n)$ is such that for any other space $X$, the set of isomorphism classes of numerable principal $O(n)$-bundles over $X$ is in bijection with the set $[X,BO(n)]$.  Let $G_n(\mathbb R^\infty)$ be the Grassman space.

I couldn't find a proof of $BO(n) = G_n(\mathbb R^\infty)$ nor could I think of one. For example, on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifying_space_for_U(n)) it simply says "construct", and, on [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/classifying+space#classification_of_bundles) (proposition 2.16), it refers readers to Hatcher's book, but that proof is the proof about the classification of vector bundles. I tried to think if the proof for vector bundles case can be translated to prove that $G_n(\mathbb R^\infty)$ is indeed the classifying space of $O(n)$. My feeling is that it works, but not sure how exactly it does.

Comment: Let $V_n(\mathbb R^\infty)$ be the space of orthogonal frames on $\mathbb R^\infty$. Then, there is a fibration $O(n)\to V_n(\mathbb R^\infty)\to G_n(\mathbb R^\infty)$. Here, $V_n(\mathbb R^\infty)$ is contractible, so $G_n(\mathbb R^\infty)=BO(n)$.

Comment: @KentaS Thanks for your comment! So $V_n(\mathbb R^\infty)$ being contractible implies it is the universal bundle? Could you provide more details or some references? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any `reasonable' topological group $G$, a contractible space $E$ with a free (continuous) $G$-action gives rise to a quotient map $q\colon E\to B$ where $B$ is the set of orbits given the quotient topology. Then $B$ is a classifying space and $q$ is a universal $G$-bundle. In particular, given another such universal bundle $q'\colon E'\to B'$ there are $G$-maps $r\colon E\to E'$ and $s\colon E\to E'$ with induced maps $\bar{r}\colon B\to B'$ and $\bar{s}\colon B'\to B$ so that $\bar{r}\circ\bar{s}$ and $\bar{s}\circ\bar{r}$ are homotopic to the identity maps, hence $B$ and $B'$ are homotopy equivalent (not equal!).

This is very standard material and can be found in introductory text books that cover bundle theory. You could try Peter May's *A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology*, section 23.8 for a brief overview.

Comment: Thanks for your reference. I think it's now in section 23.8 in his revised version. I also found a proof here: http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2020/Dannynotes.pdf, which is one of the papers from Peter May's REU.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the details of the reference but have corrected it now.